# Why does super() inherits the "wrong" class?

Tags: python, super, diamond-problem

I am looking at the diamond problem and got a question:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print("This is class A")

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        print("This is class B")
        super().__init__()

class C(A):
    def __init__(self):
        print("This is class C")
        super().__init__()

class D(B, C):
    def __init__(self):
        print("This is class D")
        super().__init__()


i = D()
```

```
This is class D
This is class B
This is class C
This is class A
```

It works as intended and that's nice, but i would like to know why the `super().__init__()` in `class B` doesn't go to `class A` and instead C is called.

If a class has a super() and it inherits from a parent class, it should go there.

If i remove it on B the code won't get to C nor A.

I know of the MRO and how it is actually going as expected:

```
>>> D.__mro__
(<class '__main__.D'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>)
```

But i don't know why.

It's very weird than the non-super() implementation of this code has the same MRO yet A is printed twice:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print("This is class A")

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        print("This is class B")
        A.__init__(self)

class C(A):
    def __init__(self):
        print("This is class C")
        A.__init__(self)

class D(B, C):
    def __init__(self):
        print("This is class D")
        B.__init__(self)
        C.__init__(self)


i = D()
```

```
(<class '__main__.D'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>)
```

Here is the opposite, i know the MRO is correct, but it's weird the actual execution doesn't go that way:

```
This is class D
This is class B
This is class A
This is class C
This is class A
```

I would like to know what is the logic behind super() behavior.

When asking this around the web pretty much everyone links me to this: https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/ but i really don't get it, his explanation seems way too technical and his examples (the few ones i understood) far more complex than they should be to explain the point...which is why i would like a...simpler explanation.

- Super() has to follow the MRO even if the inheritance on the parent class would suggest otherwise?
- Super() is unable to go to the parent class of a parent class and therefore if there is a super in a parent class it will go instead to the second inherited class?
- Also, kind of unrelated but how common is to see the diamond problem in a real, workplace enviroment? Seems like a very convoluted way to work.

Comment: A short answer is that the mro of `D` is `(D, B, C, A, object)`. It has to be because `B` and `C` inherit from `A` and so `A` has to come after.

Comment: 1. Because that's the next implementation in the MRO. That's *why* you defer to super. 2. Because you literally call it twice. Again, *that's why you defer to super*.

Comment: "If a class has a super() and it inherits from a parent class, it should go there." No, it shouldn't. That's your fundamental misunderstanding. This only works that way in the simple case of non-multiple inheritance. But *generally* speaking, `super` provides a proxy object which will defer to the *next class in the MRO*. This is why you must use `super` in all the classes participating in cooperative multiple inheritance (which is why your second example breaks).

Comment: @OlivierMelançon no that is applicable here.

Comment: `super()` is just poorly named. It should probably be called like `next_class()` or something. You're not the first person to have this confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to keep in mind that the MRO is not just a simple follow-the-leader.  It creates a graph-like structure and resolves identical inheritances to avoid duplication.  In your first example, you have created a diamond inheritance.

```
   A
  / \
 B   C
  \ /
   D
```

The MRO seeks resolution of methods from the first level up (the immediate parent classes), from left to right (`B` then `C`), then the next level up, from left to right (just `A` here), and so on.

In this case, because you have both `B` and `C` inheriting from `A`, the top level resolves to a single `A` and creates the diamond diagram above.

Let's look at your second example:

```
class D(B, C):
    def __init__(self):
        print("This is class D")
        B.__init__(self)
        C.__init__(self)
```

By implementing it this way, you are effectively by-passing the MRO.  You have taken the inheritance diamond and made it an inheritance olive fork that looks like this:

```
 A   A
 |   |
 B   C
  \ /
   D
```

Because of this you are calling the initialization of `A` twice, which does not need to occur.  In long inheritance chains or complicated initialization routines, this is very inefficient.